# How do I make my Unity application quit programmatically?

Tags: unity, c#

I made a script and I want to make my game quit, but this does not work. How should I go to make the app quit?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour {
  public int Index;

  public void SceneLoad()
  {
    SceneManager.LoadScene(Index);
  }

  public void Quit()
  {
    Application.Quit;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the code below

```
public void QuitGame()
{
    Application.Quit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check for some button in `Update()`, for example, `Esc` (PC) or `Back` (Mobile):

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, this answer assumes that your code works and the only problem is that the `Application.Quit ()` command does not execute.

The `Application.Quit ()` command does not work when testing the application in the **Unity Editor** (for example, by pressing the "Play" button). It would close the **Unity Editor**.

To test, go to the "Files / Build and Run" menu.

This will build and execute the project and `Application.Quit()` will be execute properly.

Comment: This question already has an accepted answer from three years ago. While I appreciate the effort to add more information, it looks like the original asker's problem was just that they forgot the parentheses on `Application.Quit()`

Answer (score -2):

Application.Quit() method should be inside the Update() message inside a conditional statement wating becoming true to end the application.

Comment: I wonder how your answer differs from what has already been posted?

Comment: This answer is also not always true. Since the method shown here is public, it could be called from another script, or from a UI button event, even if it's not in Update.